# Sort list content to new lists

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have an unsorted list with an unknown amount of items, in the range of 1000. These items all contain a label that determines where it is supposed to go. To avoid iterating over every item in the list several times, I want to split this list into a certain number of sublists that contain only the items of certain labels.

```
List<Item> allItems = getItemsFromSomewhere();

List<Item> itemsLabeledA1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Item> itemsLabeledA2 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Item> itemsLabeledB1 = new ArrayList<>();
...
List<Item> itemsLabeledL3 = new ArrayList<>();
```

To further complicate the issue, some of the lists require a *range* of items to be added, which is why each item is labeled something like "A1", "A2", "A3". These lists require *every* item with an A-label to be added to them. Not all labels have these aggregate lists, however. I might have to aggregate all A-labeled items, while not aggregating all B-labeled items, while still sorting A1, B1, etc. in their own lists.

Given the example above, how do I elegantly split the full list in a single iteration? My initial thought was using ifs or a switch block, but that is an ugly solution.

```
allItems.forEach(item -> {
    if (item.getLabel().contains("A1")) { 
       itemsLabeledA1.add(item);
       allItemsLabeledA.add(item);
    }
    else if (item.getLabel().contains("B1")) itemsLabeledB1.add(item);
    ...
    else if (item.getLabel().contains("L3")) itemsLabeledL3.add(item);
});
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Could you create a dictionary using the label as a key and add the items that way instead? You wouldn't just need any if statement or switch logic that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function)) in two separate streaming operations:

```
Map<String, List<Item>> allByLabel = allItems.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getLabel));

Map<String, List<Item>> allByLabelStart = allItems.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(item -> item.getLabel().substring(0, 1)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try using a `HashMap` where the key is the labels and the values are the sublists?

```
HashMap<String, List<Item>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Item>>();
for (String label : labels) {
    map.put(label, new List<Item>);
}
allItems.forEach(item -> {
    String label = item.getLabel();
    map.get(label).add(item);
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't make the labels up at the beginning, I would do an if check to see if a list already exists with that label, otherwise create one.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are *classifying* your items. For this, you'd need to create different groups as per your specification, then add each item to its group. If I understood correctly your requirement, you could accomplish this as follows:

```
Map<String, List<Item>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>(); // keeps insertion order
allItems.forEach(it -> {
    String lbl = it.getLabel();
    map.computeIfAbsent(lbl, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(it);
    if (needsToBeAggregated(lbl)) {
        map.computeIfAbsent(lbl.substring(0, 1), k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(it);
    }
});
```

Where `boolean needsToBeAggregated(String label)` is some method where you decide whether the item should be added to an aggregate group or not.

This solution doesn't use streams, but Java 8's [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) method instead.